# TKinter object movement

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I'm working with this code for a pong game but I'm not that good with TKinter, I was wondering if anyone knew how to make the object in question move from left to right as well as up and down.

```
def key(self, event):
    global player1,player2
    print ("pressed"), repr(event.char)
        if event.char == 'w':
            if self.canvas.coords(self.paddle1)[1]>=0:
                self.canvas.move(self.paddle1,0,-self.paddleSpeed)
            if event.char == 'a':
                if self.canvas.coords(self.paddle1)[0]>=0:
                    self.canvas.move(self.paddle1,0,-self.paddleSpeed)
            if event.char == 's':
                if self.canvas.coords(self.paddle1)[3]<=self.winHEIGHT:
                    self.canvas.move(self.paddle1,0,self.paddleSpeed)
            if event.char == 'd':
                if self.canvas.coords(self.paddle1)[2]<=self.winWIDTH:
                    self.canvas.move(self.paddle1,0,self.paddleSpeed)

def motion(self, event):
    coords1 = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle1)
    width1 = coords1[2]-coords1[0]
    height1 = coords1[3]-coords1[1]
    coords1[2] = event.x
    coords1[1] = event.y
    coords1[0] = event.x+width1
    coords1[3] = event.y+height1
    self.canvas.coords(self.paddle1,coords1[0],coords1[1],coords1[2],coords1[3])
```

Comment: Is the objective to move the player or move the canvas while keeping the player still to make it look like you are moving?

Comment: I should explain, it's a pong game so the object you're moving is a paddle

Comment: Ok so you just want to move the paddle left and right now along with up and down right?  Just set an `event.char == 'a'` and use the move with a different dx value, like `-self.paddleSpeed`

Comment: It's just math: change the y coordinate to move up and down, change the x coordinate to move right and left.

Comment: there's also a second function motion, would anything need to be added to this to make it work?

Comment: Well if you want the motion function to move in the X plane you'd need to modify it accordingly.  So just like with your event.char key presses have Y movement for a W or S key press, maybe you have a motion Y and a motion X that handles the movement.

Comment: This is what I've done but it's not working, have I made a mistake somewhere?